# How to express, in java, a textsize to be accepted in different resolutions?

Tags: android

To get the dimensions of each particular device, I have written this code:

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
if (windowManager != null) {
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
}
int ancho = metrics.widthPixels;
int alto = metrics.heightPixels;
```

However, when I play with this dimension (for example: ...`setTextSize (ancho/45)`), it shows different sizes in different resolutions. Could you help me to solve this problem? In XML, using different layouts, I can work ir out using different sizes (for example: `android:textSize="16sp"/"20sp"/"24sp"`...), but not in JAVA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking a lot about it, and searching for information in other places in the forum, I got the correct solution:

```
    float SCREEN_DENSITY = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    my_textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (desiredTextHeightInSP / SCREEN_DENSITY));
```

My "desiredTextHeightInSP" and "my_textView" in my above problem were "btnTag" and "ancho/45".

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and, of course, it works. However, the problem continues, not only with 14 (in your solution) but also with the variable “ancho” I wrote (ancho/45). With 14, the size is good in mobiles but too small in tablets.